# Conditional field values with Azure DevOps Work Item Rules

Tags: azure-devops

I have added 2 custom fields in the Bug work item type on our Azure DevOps cloud environment:

- Customer Prefix (Picklist) - customer abbreviation used as an ID for the customer (e.g. ACME)
- Customer Name (Text) - full customer name (e.g. ACME International Road Repair, Inc.)

**Is it possible to auto populate Customer Name when I select Customer Prefix?**

I have tried a Work Item Rule on the Bug work item type, but it requires me to setup a new rule for each customer I add.  There does not seem to be a way to provide a lookup table (mapping).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to auto populate Customer Name when I select Customer
> Prefix?

It's able to do this through work item rules

You could add custom rules to the Bug work item on Azure DevOps, which allowing you to go beyond setting a default value for a field or make it required. Rules allow you to clear the value of a field, copy a value into a field, and **apply values based on dependencies between different fields' values**.

However, as you have pointed out, it's only apply to one customer Name / Prefix for each rule.

There is no such mapping table. If you have multiple customers, you may have to manually select Customer Prefix (Picklist) and input Customer Name.

You can check the document [Add a rule to a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) for some more details.